# Does build number matter when rooting phone?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, rooting, samsung-galaxy-ace

I want to root a Galaxy Ace S5830, Android `2.3.6` Build Number `GINGERBREAD.DXKT5`.

I've seen some tutorials that says specific build numbers while some says nothing specific.

Does build number matter when rooting phone?

BTW if you have any tips on how to specifically root this (`2.3.6` `GINGERBREAD.DXKT5`), that would be cool.

Comment: It shouldn't matter for a Samsung device, I think it mostly matters when it comes to devices with locked bootloaders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, build number rarely matters.

The main reason to note the build number is because of the baseband - but I normally take no notice of the build number.

Comment: build number does not matter _per se_, but it is an easily trackable indication. For example, some devices are available for different carriers. Some carrier has locked bootloader, or other complications, and another does not. But instead of explaining all the tiny details, it's enough to provide the build number - if it's the same, that guarantees that the same recepy will work.